# How to import pyspark UDF into main class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have two files. `functions.py` has a function and creates a pyspark udf from that function. `main.py` attempts to import the udf. However, `main.py` seems to have trouble accessing the function in `functions.py`.

functions.py:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def do_something(x):
    return x + 'hello'

sample_udf = udf(lambda x: do_something(x), StringType())
```

main.py:

```
from functions import sample_udf, do_something
df = spark.read.load(file)
df.withColumn("sample",sample_udf(col("text")))
```

This results in an error:

```
17/10/03 19:35:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6, ip-10-223-181-5.ec2.internal, executor 3): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 164, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 93, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 55, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'do_something'
```

If I bypass the `do_something` function and just put it inside the udf, eg: `udf(lambda x: x + ' hello', StringType())`, the UDF imports fine - but my function is a little longer and it would be nice to have it encapsulated in a separate function. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: So you could import the function and encapsulate in the main function i.e wrap the function in the `udf` then. But to be honest have you tried running it without importing the `do_something` since you only use udf?

Comment: I've tried a variations of:
* Import just the udf
* Import the `do_something`, create the udf in main
* Create the `do_something` in main, import the udf

all of which result in the same error unfortunately

Comment: @ayplam add your py file to sparkcontext in order to make it available to your executors.
sc.addPyFile("functions.py")
from functions import sample_udf

Here is my test notebook
https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3669221609244155/3140647912908320/868274901052987/latest.html

Comment: This solved it! Thank you! If I can flag this as an answer I would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just adding this as answer:-

add your py file to sparkcontext in order to make it available to your executors.

```
sc.addPyFile("functions.py")
from functions import sample_udf
```

Here is my test notebook

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3669221609244155/3140647912908320/868274901052987/latest.html

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 5):

I think a cleaner solution would be to use the udf decorator to define your udf function :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@F.udf
def sample_udf(x):
     return x + 'hello'
```

With this solution, the udf does not reference any other function and you don't need the `sc.addPyFile` in your main code.

```
from functions import sample_udf, do_something
df = spark.read.load(file)
df.withColumn("sample",sample_udf(col("text")))
# It works :)
```

For some older versions of spark, the decorator doesn't support typed udf some you might have to define a custom decorator as follow :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as t

# Custom udf decorator which accept return type
def udf_typed(returntype=t.StringType()):
    def _typed_udf_wrapper(func):
        return F.udf(func, returntype)
    return _typed_udf_wrapper

@udf_typed(t.IntegerType())
def my_udf(x)
    return int(x)
```